# Step implementation missing for: I login to the app in cypress cucumber

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have the cypress with `cucumber-step-definition` library.
I tried running the `feature` file and it doesn't work.

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.6.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/**/"
  }
}
```

**plugin/index.js**

```
const cucumber =require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor',cucumber())
}
```

**cypress/integration/page-step/login-step.js**

```
import {Given,When,Then, And} from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
Given(/^I login to the app$/, function () {
});
Then(/^I see login on the account$/, function () {
});
```

cypress/integration/Login.feature

```
Feature: User buy a product on the website
  Scenario: Buying a grocery with a proper test
    Given I login to the app
    Then I see login on the account
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the link to the library you are using ?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.6.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/**/"
  }
}

Comment: Is all your step definition files inside `integration` folder? Please add a screenshot of the project structure.

Comment: @AlapanDas Apologies for the late response. I added

Comment: The folder structure in your screenshots isn't matching the file paths you added at the start of the question (see `cypress/integration/page-step/login-step.js` and `cypress/integration/Login.feature`), maybe that's causing the issue?

I was able to get the test running using the code you shared above (before the screenshots). Putting the step definitions in `integration/page-step/login-step.js` & the feature in `integration/Login.feature`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the issue as It happened to me as well. I tired this in my plugin and then it works.

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
}
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```